# Check my tuple of tuples and change the given value

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples

So, i'm doing the tic tac toe game, with a tuple of 3 tuples. (3x3 matrix)

my function is:
def do_position(board, player, position):
I want to return my new board with the new value, like this:

> board = ((1,-1,0),(1,0,-1),(1,-1,0))

> do_position(board, -1, 5)

((1, -1, 0), (1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 0))

board is my tuple, player will be a value (-1(for 0 player) or 1(for X player)), and position is my tuple position where I want to put my int (-1 or 1).

I know I have to turn my tuple into lists so I can reach the position I want, but i've tried many ways and my output still return my initial board without any change.
Here's one of my attempts:

```
def do_position(board,player, position):

   newboard = ()

   position=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

   player = (-1,1)
    
    for p in position:
        board[position[p]-1] = player[p]
    
    for position,player in enumerate(board):
        if player == 1:
           board[position] = 1
        elif player == -1:
             board[position] = -1
return newboard
```

Can anyone give some help?

Comment: Can you give ```def do_position(board, player, position):``` function code ??

Comment: you are returning **newboard**. when you did changes to **newboard** ??

Comment: @akash right! i didn't! And I need something to see if my position is 0 so I could change that position for player(-1 or 1)

Comment: checkout the answer if it statisfies your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tuple is immutable meaning you can't change value of tuple.**

So you have 3 options so far --

1. Regenerate the board with changed value.
2. convert tuple to list, make changes and convert back to tuple
3. Use changeable collection of python like list `board = [[1,-1,0],[1,0,-1],[1,-1,0]]`

Alternate Working Code:

```
def do_position(board,player, position):
    position-=1
    row,col=position//3,position%3
    board[row][col]=player
    return board

board = [[1,-1,0],[1,0,-1],[1,-1,0]]
do_position(board, -1, 3)
```

For tuple board :

```
def tuple_to_list(board):
    return [list(x) for x in board]

def list_to_tuple(board):
    return tuple([tuple(x) for x in board])

def do_position(board,player, position):
    temp_board=tuple_to_list(board)
    position-=1
    row,col=position//3,position%3
    temp_board[row][col]=player
    return list_to_tuple(temp_board)

board = ((1,-1,0),(1,0,-1),(1,-1,0))
do_position(board, -1, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you @akash ! just one thing, my board is a tuple. I need to put inside the function that right? I want this to happen: >board = ((1,-1,0),(1,0,-1),(1,-1,0))
>do_position(board, -1, 5)

Comment: just convert ```tuple --> list --> tuple```

Comment: @CateC i have updated my answer. if it is ok, check as correct answer

Comment: thank you! you helped me a lot! Can you give me a hand with one more question?